# Bypassed authentication in route handling

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I have set up an application with a registration homepage and a few internal pages requiring a login. 
I used Node with Express.js to set up the server and controlling the routes and authentication works fine: if I try to access localhost:port/clientPage I get the desired page if I previously logged in and an error message otherwise.

The problem is that if I try to access localhost:port/clientPage.*html* I get the clientPage even when I have no active session. How can I ensure the same - desired - behaviour previously described also in this case? I attach the code of my GET route to clientPage:

```
router.get('/clientPage', function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('Not authorized! Go back!');
          err.status = 400;
          return next(err);
        } else {
          return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/clientPage.html'));
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try router.get('/clientPage*',     in first line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the behaviour doesn't change

Comment: What's the value of user when you have no active session? (Are you sure it is `null` and not `undefined` or something?)

Comment: @CodyG.it is null

Comment: Okay, so your question is really about how to detect a timed-out session? Does req.session not include some sort of timestamp (client-side cookie)? What are you using to store your session? If it's server-side why don't you look up the session and then once again check if it's timed out?

Comment: No, I already controlled authentication and it works fine, until I add a ".html" to the URL. This results in the requested page disregarding the session state.

Comment: You should get a `404` if you are just adding `.html`.. (unless you do some sort of other `Not found` handling) Can you verify that this route (the one you posted) is the one being fired and that no subsequent routes (any routes following it) are being fired?

Comment: In my router.js file the only subsequent routes are adminPage and logout and I can assert that none of them is called. In app.js I have only a 404 catcher and then a generic error handler.

Comment: I tried also to add console logs in every route I have defined: when I access to URL (localhost:port/clientPage.html) none of them is called, but the page appears anyway.

Comment: Hmmm. Browser cache? Is the page actually served when you go to `.html`? (Now I'm questioning why it doesn't 404)

Comment: It's not the cache because route should in any case control the behaviour on the requested URL. Anyway I tried it with a never used before browser and I had the same issue: cache is definitely not the answer to the problem.

Comment: Remove your /clientPage route and check that both /clientPage and /clientPage.html `404`  --- Also, have you tried setting a debug breakpoint on that route and look at what it is returning such that the conditional statement for the user is not null when using `.html`?

Comment: Also, what express/node version are you running?

Comment: have you tried clearing cache to rule out that it was indeed not a cache?

Comment: did you use any kind of `express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")` possbily serving your `views`?

Comment: Conferming my last comment, removing the /clientPage route results in a 404 if I access /clientPage, while still shows the entire page when accessing /clientPage.html.
I'm using Express 4.16.2 and Node 8.8.1

Comment: Ooo. Yes, I agree with Zanko at this point.

Comment: @Zanko yes, in app.js {app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));}
I understand now that this was the problem - and it seems a very stupid one, but If you want to provide an answer I'll accept it - but why this overrided all the specified routes showing the html files?

Comment: Moreover, dropping that line I can't access neither the root anymore

Comment: @alex what were you using views publically for previously? Normally we do `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to serve static content like images, css. javascript file.

Comment: So you suggest to put in /public all the javascript utilities, css, images AND index.html and in /views all the other .html which should not be directly accessible, right?

Comment: index.html could go in /views too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is caused by adding `.html` to the end of the route that somehow bypassed the authentication route. I think it is highly possible that you have

`express.static(path.join(__dirname, "views")` at the beginning of your application publicly serving your folder.

**Why is it overriding your route?**

Express is running middleware sequentially through `app.use(...)`. The statement `app.use(express.static...)` is placed before `app.use(// your router)` and the response was resolved to client early.

Using this knowledge you can easily restrict other route by placing an authentication middleware before your route instead of embedding your database call inside each specific route.

```
app.use(require("./middleware/auth"));
app.use("/homepage", require("./routes/homepage"));
app.use("/clientPage", require("./routes/clientPage"));
```

Comment: It's a very good idea, I should try this kind of implementation. However, some points are not clear to me and for the sake of clarity I'll post a separate question. If you don't mind I'd be glad to read your answer there.

Comment: @Alex sure I am happy to clarify

Comment: Thank you, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515991/how-to-setup-an-authentication-middleware-in-express-js